# php and sql query from dropdowns

Tags: php, mysql

i have 6 dropdown in php. user can select one dropdown or all, and based on user selection i need to run an mysql query. My problem is that if i use AND, user must select an option from all drops. If i use OR the result are very very strange. I need a solution for combined values selection and when i click on a table to open a link with the results. i have this for now:

```
        <select name="categorie" class="form-control m-bot15"> 
        <option value= option 1> Option 1 </option> 
        <option value= option 2> Option 2 </option>
    </select>

    <select name="employeename" class="form-control m-bot15"> 
        <option value= option 1> Option 1 </option> 
        <option value= option 2> Option 2 </option>
    </select>

    etc....

    <?php  
    if(isset($_GET['from'])){ $from = $_GET['from']; }
    if(isset($_GET['to'])){ $to = $_GET['to']; }
    $agenti = $_GET['agenti'];
    $task = $_GET['task'];
    $categorie = $_GET['categorie'];
    $clienti = $_GET['clienti'];
    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT distinct ch.employeename, ch.customername, ch.QuestionnaireName, ch.parentgroupname, 
                                ch.groupname, vd.visitdate, vd.customerowner from chestionare ch
                                inner join visitdetails vd on vd.visitid =  ch.visitid
                                WHERE vd.visitdate >= '".$_GET['from']."' AND vd.visitdate <= '".$_GET['to']."' OR 
                                 ch.employeename= '$agenti' OR ch.questionnairename= '$task' OR ch.parentgroupname= '$categorie' OR vd.customerowner= '$clienti'
                                    ") 
                                or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ 
        while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){ 
    ?>

            <tr>
                <td><?php echo '<a href="g_angajat.php?name='.$agenti.'&from='.$from.'&to='.$to.'&clienti='.$clienti.'&task='.$task.'&categorie='.$categorie.'">' ?>    <?php echo $results['employeename']; ?></a></td>
                .... table for each dropdown
            </tr>


      <?php  } }?>
```

can someone help me? thx

Comment: can you provide the 6 drop down sample values.

Comment: Could you further explain what is the desired return from your query? Also, how are you building the query?

Comment: <select name="categorie" class="form-control m-bot15">
<option value= option 1> Option 1 </option> <option value= option 2> Option 2 </option>                       </select> All 6 are the same with different names.

Comment: i have added my code.

Answer (score 0):

solved like this:

```
 $employeename= $_GET['employeename'];

 <select name="employeename">
 <option value="%">All Employees</option>
 <option value="John"John</option>
 </select>
 ...... x 6 times with different name for each select
```

now in mysql:

```
 SELECT distinct ch.employeename, ch.customername, ch.QuestionnaireName,   ch.parentgroupname, 
 ch.groupname, vd.visitdate, vd.customerowner from chestionare ch
 inner join visitdetails vd on vd.visitid =  ch.visitid
  WHERE vd.visitdate >= '".$_GET['from']."' AND vd.visitdate <= '".$_GET['to']."' AND
  ch.employeename like '$employeename' AND ch.questionnairename like '$task' AND ch.parentgroupname like '$parentgroupname' AND vd.customerowner like '$customers'
```

results:
if you will select from employee dropdown JOHN, it will return only result for employee JOHN. If from the same dropdown you will select ALL Employees, it will return result for all employees. The same tehnic for every other dropdown and works great when combined.

:)) so simple.